# Call stored procedure with optional parameters using OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using OrmLite to call stored procedure that has optional parameters.

```
_dbConnection.SqlList<CustomerDTO>("sp_getcustomers @name", new { name = request.Name });
```

This statement is generating dynamic sql statement with @name as parameter. But I am not knowing how to pass null to this parameter, I tried using DBNull.Value but its not working. 
Exception : *The given key was not present in the dictionary* is raised.

```
_dbConnection.SqlList<CustomerDTO>("sp_getcustomers @name", new { name = request.Name ??  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null});
```

Answer (score 3):

See these [SqlProviderTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/SqlServerProviderTests.cs) for examples of how to effectively make use of OrmLite's `Sql*` apis.

The right way to call it is with something like:

```
Db.SqlList<CustomerDTO>("EXEC sp_getcustomers @Name", new { request.Name });
```

Comment: Sorry, that was psuedo code that I've written, rectified it. Problem here is I am able to call SP, if I pass some value or a blank name parameter. But I have logic in DB which checks for name =null, so by using above syntax, I am not able to pass null or completely avoid passing name parameter (which is done in ADO.NET)

Comment: "Must declare the scalar variable @Name" exception is raised when I try to pass null.

Comment: Generated SQL : exec sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.sp_getcustomers @name',N'@name nvarchar(20)' . There is no declaration for name parameter. With Dapper, generated sql is, exec dbo.sp_getcustomers @name=NULL

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I can't figure out how to set a parameter to NULL.  Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I created a question more specific to my problem (non-optional parameters) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432909/how-to-pass-non-optional-null-parameters-to-a-stored-proc-using-ormlite

Comment: How to do something like this with ORMLite when you do not know the shape of the object you will get back? Drop it to an object? Db.SqlList<Object>(...)

Comment: Does this work with ServiceStack version 3.9.69.0? What about the `ExecuteProcedure` method, which I can't find *any* documentation for?

Answer (score 1):

Ormlite has a [T4 file](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/T4) to generate C# functions equivalents for the SPs (for SqlServer); the generated files allows you to pass null values.

Answer (score 0):

Support for null parameters in stored procedures was added in [commit e6ef83a](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/e6ef83a6fcadb8fa41a1107063332302c37eaf86) and released with [version 3.9.56](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/3.9.56) of ServiceStack.OrmLite.